# Deleting random rows from np array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

I am working in ML, and want to take 20% of my data at random to use as validation. This is my current implementation:

```
x_train = np.transpose(np.array(x))
test_index = np.random.randint(0,len(x_train), math.floor(len(x_train)/5))
x_test = x_train[test_index]
x_train = np.delete(x_train, test_index, 0)
print(x_train.shape)
print(x_test.shape)
```

However, the new `x_train` doesn't have the correct length: I have 1092 rows to begin with, `x_test` always ends up with 218 rows, but the new length seems to be random. Like so:

```
for i in range(5) :
    x_train = np.transpose(np.array(x))
    print(len(x_train))
    test_index = np.random.randint(0,len(x_train), math.floor(len(x_train)/5))
    x_test = x_train[test_index]
    x_train = np.delete(x_train, test_index, 0)
    print(x_train.shape)
    print(x_test.shape)
    print(len(x_train) + len(x_test))
    print("+++++")
```

> 1092
> (896, 48)
> (218, 48)
> 1114
> +++++
> 1092
> (899, 48)
> (218, 48)
> 1117
> +++++
> 1092
> (894, 48)
> (218, 48)
> 1112
> +++++
> 1092
> (898, 48)
> (218, 48)
> 1116
> +++++
> 1092
> (899, 48)
> (218, 48)
> 1117
> +++++

I think what is happening is that `np.delete()` is deleting each row one by one, so once it reaches the end of `test_index`, some of the indexes are out of range and not deleted (which would imply that it is also not deleting the correct rows). How do I work around that? Is this behaviour expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `test_index = np.random.randint(0,len(x_train), math.floor(len(x_train)/5))` makes duplicate numbers in your range.
You can use this code instead:

```
test_index = np.random.choice(range(1092), math.floor(len(x_train)/5, replace=False)
```